# How to convert rows into columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have rows called studentname and college. How can I convert this rows into columns with SQL?

Comment: Please edit & add a tag for the specific DB you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying a transpose operation..Let us consider this table for E.g:

### TYPE DESCRIPTION

1. AAKASH
2. DJSCOE

To convert it to columns you can use this query which uses TYPE column:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT TYPE, DESCRIPTION
    FROM TRANSPOSE
  )
  PIVOT ( 
   COUNT(TYPE)
    FOR TYPE in ('1','2')
);
```

**Note:** PIVOT is supported only from Oracle 11g onwards.

Concept: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Enjoy..